# How to open Object class of java.lang package in eclipse ide?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, superclass

How to open the Object class of java.lang package in eclipse ide? Every class in java is directly or indirectly derived from the Object class, hence it is a child of the Object class. So how do I view this Object class in eclipse ide?

Object class is the default parent class of all the classes in java but I just want to open this class file in eclipse ide. I'm unable to do it. How to open this class file?

Comment: Navigate > Open Type... and type in Object. It is not all that interesting as a lot of methods are `native`

Answer (score 0):

Hold on ctrl key and right click on any class you want see source code.